# Pentaho Generating report and scheduling mail job with attachment

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

I am very new in Pentaho. can anyone guide me how to create report in PDF file and sending over mail as attachment on schedule basis using PDI .Any tutorial or demo will help

Comment: Entreprise edition or Community Edition? Are you using the BA Server or do you plan to schedule with crontabs ?

Comment: I am using community edition and yes i am also using BA server for scheduling

Answer (score 0):

If you are the administrator, you can do it yourself by following the below documentation.

How to schedule reports?

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0L0/120/060

How to setup a Mail server to send those scheduled reports?

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0H0/Set_Up_Emails_for_Scheduled_Reports

Answer (score 0):

- Pentaho data integration has a very simple utility for this.
- Execute your report in PDI and use email step to send report.